# Why re2 result different from re module in Python?

Tags: python, regex, re2

I try to use [re2](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/re2/).

```
import re
print re.search('cde', 'abcdefg').group(0)
```

Result:

```
cde
```

But re2 result is different

```
import re2
print re2.search('cde', 'abcdefg').group(0)
```

Result:

```
1
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```

1. Why `re2` output number **1** when every execution new string pattern?
2. How to hide the number **1**?
3. Why the result is different with `re module` (not found => return None)?

**The re2 version is 0.2.20.** and **Python is 2.7**

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a bug of version 0.2.20. See this [issue](https://github.com/axiak/pyre2/issues/11) or this [one](https://github.com/axiak/pyre2/issues/14). You'd better clone the source from github and then install it. Don't install it via pip.

Comment: Oh, the issue had been resolved by github version. Thank you.